# 14.04 random hanging on boot

Tags: boot, grub2, 14.04

I've already googled a lot and probably know what's wrong but don't know how to fix it.
Fresh install of Trusty Tahr LTS i386 on a new netbook with an Intel N2820 Bay Trail graphics.

Average 4 of 5 boots hang up when it tries to change the screen resolution and must be turned off by the power button. **Then it boots normally and everything is fine**, graphics is accelerated.

**BAD**: "Hidden" grub for 3 seconds, "Starting up" in a low-res, usually a black screen for a second and then "Starting up" in a low-res forever.
**GOOD**: the same, "Starting up" in a low-res changes to high-res 1366x768, then more lines roll down and then the purple screen appears and then login screen.

I tried to play with /etc/default/grub options and it worked until I reinstalled the grub package and installed grub at /dev/sda. Now it seems that **/etc/default/grub is completely ignored** (sudo update-grub processed each time).

I tried various tips (removed "quiet splash", added "acpi off", "console terminal") but it's still the same.

Note: Recovery mode hangs too. It also doesn't halt/reboot - (this is the last line displayed) and the power button must be used but this is just a background - not a big problem for me.
Any help appreciated!

Comment: The /etc/default/grub is completely ignored solved. By reinstalling grub I downgraded from Grub 2.02 to Grub 0.97. Grub-pc 2.02 installed but hanging still occurs...

Answer (score 2):

Accept it.

... the fact that your (or any other) Bay Trail device is hopeless crippleware.
Bay Trail reboots into a completely different random universe.
 each and every time the power button is depressed.
Conceivably, you might try `i915.modeset=1` in your grub options,
 but don't get your hopes up.

Condolences are in order  :
  It is almost as if there is a hard-wired random number generator 
 attached to the power button.
It starts with faulty pin control, arising from the fact that some
 of the power controls have default states that do not get reset
 upon power on power off cycling.

And cannot be fixed. Ever.

Intel Bay Trail is a spectacular train wreck complete with super-size-me body bags,
 due to some overlooked architecture issues which the Intel folks
 seem to so nonchalantly overlook prior to market release.

from http://www.bit-tech.net/news/hardware/2014/04/24/intel-n2820/1

> " Intel has officially discontinued its Celeron N2820 Bay Trail chip
>   mere months after launch..."

Their 'release to market, oops, then fix the bugs modus operandi' is so much fun:

> "Some of those flaws, it would appear, have been traced back to the
>   processor's design"

Windows has the same problem and it cannot be patched over - it just stutters a lot.
These crippleware kits always come with Win 8 installed,
 I should have known better than to blithely assume because it had Win 8 we could
 simply replace it and proceed at pace.

I paid good money for a (Kick me again if I ever buy another SoC cesspool from ACER)
 Iconia W4-821 with 3740 Bay Trail and I have been on a rocket-launch learning curve.

Google "fedlet" or "bay trail kernel" to see what a bunch of us who deluded ourselves
 into spending time and money on BAY TRAIL and you will see what is involved. 
Kudos to the guys who got there first and shined a bright light on the issues:

Adam Williamson "Fedlet"  (he is an ex-Mandriva rock star from way back).

Jerry Wells "Ubuntu on Asus Transformer Book T100"

...but the juiciest comments are in the kernel mailing list,
 where some of the guys who are trying to patch the linux kernel
 to accommodate faulty Intel hardware have some interesting perspectives:

Quoted - I kid you not ! - from

https://lkml.org/lkml/2014/2/11/962

```
Re: Baytrail/T (ASUS T100 etc) regression from 3.13 onwards
```

> Ugg, so reverting a real fix to make the T100TA work by accident...
>   this is ugly.
>   ... ...
>
> > A module paramater to fix a bug? Ugh, that's almost worse than just
> >     reverting the original patch, right?
> >
> > Please don't do this, the distros will hate you even more than they
> >     currently do :)

I could send you videos of how random this power reboot issue is
 but it would be an utter waste of time and bandwidth.

Brick, uses power, and displays random color schemes.

...Bay Trail.